# Redux doesn't re-render the components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which takes `data` from `mapStateToProps()` method. Component's code is:

```
    handleClick = () => {
        if (this.props.data.status) {
            this.props.changeIpStatus(index, !this.props.data.status);

        } else {
            this.props.changeIpStatus(index, !this.props.data.status);

        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.data.status) {
            this.switchClasses = `switcher blocked`;
            this.dotClasses = `dot blocked`;
        } else {
            this.switchClasses = `switcher`;
            this.dotClasses = `dot`;
        }
        return (
            <div className="block">
                <div onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.switchClasses}>
                    <div className={this.dotClasses}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My `Redux` connection looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.ipTable.data.clicks,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeIpStatus: (index, status) => {
            return dispatch(changeIpStatus(index, status));
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BlockSwitcher)
```

When I click switcher it should re-render because the data is changed. I see that the data is changed through my console log. But it doesn't invoke re-render. Why? My component have mapStateToProps with data that changing and action import is correct (checked).

**UPDATE:**
This is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    data: {}
}

const ipReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case `SET_CLICKS`:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }

        case `CHANGE_IP_STATUS`:
            let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
            newState.data.clicks[action.index].status = action.status;
            return newState;

        default: return state;
    }
}

export default ipReducer;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm afraid that you are mutating your state in reducer case `CHANGE_IP_STATUS` (`Object.assign` doesn't deep clone objects)

Comment: any advise how to deep clone?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))` or `import deepClone from 'lodash/deepClone'`

Comment: It will be easier do debug if you provide the entire code of your BlockSwitcher component (maybe omitting irrelevant functions).

And you write that you see the data changing through console.logs, but where have you written the console.log()? It's quite important in order to determine how the data is handled through its lifecycle (and possible where it went wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` method but be aware of that if your state includes a non-serializable property then you lose it.

Here is an alternative approach. You can see this method more frequently.

```
// map the clicks, if index match return the new one with the new status
// if the index does not match just return the current click

const newClicks = state.data.clicks.map((click, index) => {
  if (index !== action.index) return click;
  return { ...click, status: action.status };
});

// Here, set your new state with your new clicks without mutating the original one

const newState = { ...state, data: { ...state.data, clicks: newClicks } };
return newState;
```

The second alternative would be like that. Without mapping all the `clicks` we can use `Object.assign` for the `clicks` mutation.

```
const newClicks = Object.assign([], state.data.clicks, {
  [action.index]: { ...state.data.clicks[action.index], status: action.status }
});

const newState = { ...state, data: { ...state.data, clicks: newClicks } };
return newState;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with deep copy of an object. In JavaScrip for copying object without any reference between them we have to use, for example:

```
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

not this:

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, state); // <-- this is do not return a standalone new object. Do not use it in your reducer.
```

Thanks to @kind user!

P.S This is an [article](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab) with examples why Object.assign() do not work in this case.

Comment: Is the `clicks` property is an array?

Comment: @devserkan Yes, it is

Comment: Then let me another alternative answer. Since this method does not work if all the state properties are not serializable.

Comment: You can use the spread operator `const newState = { ...state }`

Comment: @sridharreddy spread operator will do the job with deep copying?

Comment: No, it does not. It is the same as  `Object.assign`, just does a shallow copy.

Comment: @devserkan sure, give the alternative answer and I will accept it.